How do I get the positive series expansion of $(e^{\alpha x}-1)^{-1}$?
I couldn't figure out how the second line came out in the expression below.

I basically have to expand $(e^{\alpha x}-1)^{-1}$ into a series, where $\alpha > 0$.
My first try was $\beta \equiv e^{\alpha x}$, $f(\beta) \equiv (\beta-1)^{-1}$,
$$f(\beta)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\beta^n}{n!}f^{(n)}(0) = -\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\beta^{n}$$
The result converges to the negative part of $(\beta-1)^{-1}$, but I need the positive part.
My next try was $g(x) \equiv (e^{\alpha x}-1)^{-1}$,
$$g(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}g^{(n)}(0) = 0$$
This clearly doesn't work, so I expanded at $x=1$
$$g(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(x-1)^n}{n!}g^{(n)}(1) = \cdots$$
The calculation gets a bit complicated, and I checked by computer that it indeed converges to the positive part that I want, but the expansion in the image above is much simpler.
I tried some others with no success, how can I expand $(e^{\alpha x}-1)^{-1}$ into its positive part as in the image?

You can use the geometric series:
$$\frac1{e^{ax}-1}=\frac{e^{-ax}}{1-e^{-ax}}=e^{-ax}\left(1+e^{-ax}+e^{-2ax}+\dots\right) $$
Note that this expansion is valid when $|e^{-ax}|<1$ (in particular it's valid in the domain of integration, i.e. when $x> 0$).
I used:
$$\frac{1}{1-y}=1+y+y^2+\dots $$

Note that (assuming $h,k>0$) $\beta=e^{hv/k} > 1$. The expansion $(1-\beta)^{-1} = \sum_{k\ge 0}\beta^k$ is only valid for $|\beta|<1$. To fix this, first rewrite as follows
$$\frac{1}{e^{hv/k}-1} = e^{-hv/k}\frac1{1-e^{-hv/k}} $$
Now put $\beta = e^{-hv/k}$ (importantly now $|\beta|<1$) to get
$$\frac{1}{e^{hv/k}-1} = e^{-hv/k} ( 1 + e^{-hv/k} + e^{-2hv/k} + \dots) = e^{-hv/k} + e^{-2hv/k} +  e^{-3hv/k} + \dots$$
